# Data variable undefined in computed function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm trying to load an image src for a lightbox using photos from my API endpoint. this.photos stores all my objects but I'm looking for the url which becomes 'this.photos[x].photos'.

Inside of gallery, I'm attempting to load `${this.photos[x].photos` as a string for the src attribute, but I keep getting an error that "photos is undefined"

I tested that the photos object isn't empty and got back "http://localhost:8000/media/uploads/1_082720_soylent_PDPwebsite_PowderPouchCacao_1468x1100_A01-PouchShot_2048x2048.jpg" for one object.

Sometimes if I refresh the page, {{ photos[2].photos }} is also undefined, but {{photos}} isn't, maybe I should use a different lifecycle hook than mounted as well for fetchPhotos?

Thanks!

**One of many photo objects stored in this.photos. To get just the image src, I call this.photos[2].photos for this example.**

```
 {
        "id": 3,
        "photos": "http://localhost:8000/media/uploads/1_082720_soylent_PDPwebsite_PowderPouchCacao_1468x1100_A01-PouchShot_2048x2048.jpg",
        "user": null
    },
```

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <CoolLightBox :items="gallery" :index="index" @close="index = null">
    </CoolLightBox>

    <div class="images-wrapper">
      <div
        class="image"
        v-for="(image, imageIndex) in items"
        :key="imageIndex"
        @click="index = imageIndex"
        :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + image + ')' }"
      ></div>
    </div>
    {{ photos[2].photos }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import CoolLightBox from "vue-cool-lightbox";
import "vue-cool-lightbox/dist/vue-cool-lightbox.min.css";

export default {
  name: "app",
  data: function() {
    return {
      photos: [],
      index: null
    };
  },
  computed: {
    galleryPhoto: function() {
      return {
        gallery: [
          {
            src: `${this.photos[2].photos}`
          }
        ]
      };
    }
  },
  components: {
    CoolLightBox
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchPhotos();
  },
  methods: {
    setIndex(index) {
      this.index = index;
    },

    fetchPhotos($axios) {
      this.$axios
        .get("/api/v1/photos/")
        .then(response => {
          // console.log(response, "response");
          this.photos = response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficul to understand your issue without more data.
How many item there is in '{{photos}} ? for instance. You say that "...{ photos[2].photos }} is also undefined, but {{photos}} isn't..." => this should means that {{photos}} hold less then 3 items, or that the 3th element of {{photos}} is undefined.

=> Could you please provide us with the content of {{photos}} ?

In addition, I guess that there is another bug in your code:
in your template you have

```
<CoolLightBox :items="gallery" :index="index" @close="index = null">
</CoolLightBox>
```

but gallery is not define in your scrip section, instead you define galleryPhoto which return an object whish has the gallery attribut:

```
   galleryPhoto: function() {
      return {
        gallery: [
          {
            src: `${this.photos[2].photos}`
          }
        ]
      };
    }
```

=> So either you modify your template to refer to galleryPhoto.gallery:

```
<CoolLightBox :items="galleryPhoto.gallery" :index="index" @close="index = null">
</CoolLightBox>
```

or a better solution is to modify the computed property:

```
  computed: {
    gallery() {
      return [
          {
            src: this.photos[2].photos
          }
        ];
    }
  },
```

Or if you want to display all the photos:

```
  computed: {
    gallery() {
      return !Array.isArray(this.photos) ? [] : this.photos.map(el => el?.photos);
    }
  },
```

Comment: Ah ok, I was a bit confused about whether I should use 'gallery', or 'galleryPhoto' thanks for clearing that up! I updated the post to show you what the data in this.photos looks like. When I use {{ photos }} in my template it displays all my photos objects (there's 10 total). That's just for testing, so it's not too big of a deal. I'm more concerned with why 'this.photos[2].photos' would be undefined in computed. The error is 'Cannot read property 'photos' of undefined'

Comment: try modifying your data name photos => photoList it is a bit confusing

Comment: and with the error message we cannot know if it is "this" or "this.photos[2]" which is undefined

Comment: OK I just understood you issue

Comment: In your template, if you put {{photos}} it works because nothing is rendered until the fetchPhotos method is complited. But if you put {{ photos[2].photos }} in your template, the rendering will fail because when rendering the first time photos === [] => photos[2] === undefined

Comment: Gotcha, changed it to photoList in data(). And yes, photosList[2] is also undefined at first inside of gallery, so I probably just need to delay when that data is injected.